# Looking for a Promiscuous Mode Packet Sniffer on Mac OS that records sending time and receiving time of packet

Tags: packet-capture

I need a software that sniffs packets and records packet type (UDP or TCP), the sending port or receiving port of the packet, and the sending time and receiving time of the packet. I also need to run that software for a certain number of seconds and be able to export the data into comma separated values (CMV) file or something similiar. Any suggestions? I need this data for a python program I am building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is [scapy](https://scapy.net/) which is itself python based. Runs on Python 2.7 & 3.4-3.8 is [installable](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) on Linux, Windows & OS-X.

It allows packet capture, *[sniffing](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#sniffing)*, (and injection), gives you the send & destination ports, timestamps & more, can be run for a fixed time or number of packets and has multiple [export options](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#importing-and-exporting-data) and you can easily write the required packet data to a .csv file.
There are even options for graphical output:
[image]
[image]